# Use Angular js API with ASP.net webForms

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am using angular js with Asp.net webforms. I want to retrieve data from database using angular js API. All I have seen on google or any tutorial , uses angular js API's with Asp.net MVC .

My question is: Can we  use angular js API with Asp.net web Forms?

If yes, then method will be the same as in Asp.net MVC?

Further I know angular js is for SPA(single page app) and it has Models views and controllers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you could.

But I really **really** don't recommend it. It might be extremely hard to ensure they are not stepping in each other toes, because they both work by enhancing the HTML.

My recommendation is that you start moving your business logic from the Web forms code behind into Service classes, so that you can expose the business logic via [WebMethods]. You could add the [WebMethods to the pages](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-web-forms---calling-web-service-page-methods-using-jquery) but it would be way better if you could add a REST web service endpoint using WebAPI.

Think of an angular SPA as completely independent from the server technology, all you need  for Angular to work with the server is an HTTP API, preferably one that returns JSON.

Comment: Many Web Forms developers have moved to Angular. There are obvious similarities between the two but they end right where they begin. Both manage state and transform and extend HTML. Again, that is where the similarities end. Think if you could pull back the hood on Web Forms using JavaScript which is something you are already familiar with to get fine grain control over controls. Remove the black box of state that web forms makes you carry around. Start with HTML & Angular and use what you know about c# to setup API endpoints instead of SQL statements that power your web forms controls.

Comment: I have an application that uses an ASPX page and I want to use the JSON data with Angular instead of using nested grid views. Would I have to create an HTML page instead of using web forms with master files?

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use angular with web forms, and you can do single page application also by using $HTTP service in angular.
i have written one ajax call by using web form.

```
<script type="text/javascript" ><src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
    app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
        $scope.ButtonClick = function () {
            var post = $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { name: $scope.Name },
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
            });

            post.success(function (data, status) {
                $window.alert(data.d);
            });

            post.error(function (data, status) {
                $window.alert(data.Message);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="Name" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="ButtonClick()" />
</div>
```